# How to solve a 4 variable polynomial equation

Tags: polynomials

I was working on a Statistics problem and had been given some data (Mean, variance, Skewness and Kurtosis values). From that, I arrived at the following 4 equations but I am stumped here. Any suggestions would greatly help, thanks !

> a + b + c + d = 20
>   (a-5)² + (b-5)² + (c-5)² + (d-5)² = 46
>   (a-5)³ + (b-5)³ + (c-5)³ + (d-5)³ = 2105.93
>   (a-5)⁴ + (b-5)⁴ + (c-5)⁴ + (d-5)⁴ = 118760.5

Comment: Start with $$a-5=A$$ etc.

Comment: From where does it come?

Comment: I would use the Goebner Method

Comment: Step 1: Calculate $a^i+b^i+c^i+d^i$ for $i=1,2,3,4$.

Step 2: Calculate the symmetric functions in $a,b,c,d$.

Step 3: Construct & solve the quartic equation. ... Good luck $ \ddot \smile$

Comment: I think it is impossible to solve it by hand.

Comment: System [reduced](http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/11.1571064702.png) to $-15519445 - 583186 x + 76200 x^2 - 12000 x^3 + 600 x^4=0$, where $x=(a,b,c,d)$.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner You should stop using WolframAlpha so much and read about [symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_polynomial) and [Ferrari's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots).

Comment: I know all these formulas,but i think they will not help at all.